# How can we send draft envelope to other recipient of envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using `Authorizatio Code Grant` for authorization and wanted to send `envelope` as `draft` to other envelope recipient(editor). But in this case it is going to `draft` of whoever is logging and sending envelope request. I can send that `envelope` to other recipient's `draft` simply using "Transfer Owenership" from sender's draft but wanted to automate this while sending `envelope` request.

Here is the `envelope` request I am sending:

```
try
 {
     // create the envelope definition
     EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition();
     env.EmailSubject = $"Please Sign - { DateTime.Now.ToString() }";

     //Get document extension
     
     var fileContentByteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\ESign1.docx");
     Document documentToSign = new Document
     {
         DocumentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileContentByteArray),
         Name = "ESign1.docx",
         FileExtension = "docx",
         DocumentId = "1"
     };

     env.Documents = new List<Document> { documentToSign };

     var signatureHandler = new Editor
     {
         Email = "abc@test.com",
         RecipientId = "1",
         RoutingOrder = "1", 
     };
     
     List<Signer> signers = new List<Signer>();

     signers.Add(new Signer { Email = "xyz@test.com", Name = "xyz", RecipientId = "3", RoutingOrder = "3" });
     signers.Add(new Signer { Email = "abc@test.com", Name = "abc", RecipientId = "2", RoutingOrder = "2" });


     // Add the recipients to the envelope object
     Recipients recipients = new Recipients
     {
         Editors = new List<Editor> { signatureHandler },
         Signers = signers
     };

     //Attache all recipients to envelope
     env.Recipients = recipients;


     //Webhook to listen envelope status
     EventNotification eventNotification = new EventNotification
     {
         IncludeDocuments = "true",
         IncludeDocumentFields = "true",
         IncludeTimeZone = "true",
         Url = "https://webhook-endpoint",
         LoggingEnabled = "true",
         EnvelopeEvents = new List<EnvelopeEvent>
         {
             new EnvelopeEvent{ EnvelopeEventStatusCode = "completed", IncludeDocuments = "true" }
         }
     };

     env.EventNotification = eventNotification;
     env.Status = "created";
     var config = new Configuration(baseUrl);
     config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);

     var apiClient = new ApiClient(baseUrl)
     {
         Configuration = config
     };

     EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
     EnvelopeSummary result = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(account_id, env).Result;
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is set the envelope to 'sent' status instead of 'created'(env.Status="sent"). This will start the workflow and allow the recipient specified to edit the envelope as you're looking for. It's important to note that this will then continue along in the workflow after that recipient has finished their action on the envelope.

If you're looking for collaboration on an envelope and it's going to be going back and forth a bit before you actually want it signed, you might want to check out [DocuSigns markup feature](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-markup).

Comment: I wanted to send envelope to specific user's draft so that he can make changes and forward to other signers. When I marking envelope status as sent then it goes into inbox of selected first recipient